# Como funciona o processos de Deploy em Golang?

Tags: deploy, golang

### Situação

Em minha empresa estamos iniciando um processo de troca de tecnologia. E uma das sugeridas foi Golang.

E um dos maiores empecilhos é o processo de deploy.

#### Experiências

Em PHP, ate por ser uma linguagem interpretada esse processo é bem simples, uma atualização de `class` ao salvar já é percebia na próxima *request*.

Em JAVA é bem complexa e ate mesmo necessita reiniciar o serviço. (eu sei que existem meio para deixar isso mais simples, não vou entrar nesse quesito).

### Duvida

Go, por ser uma linguagem compilada também, sofre do mesmo problema do JAVA, ou existe algum meio para fazer o deploy de modo rápida, sem reiniciar o serviço e praticamente imperceptível ao usuário final?

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Sua pergunta está bastante ampla (ao meu ver). Qual o cenário em que está fazendo o deploy da aplicação?

Comment: Pesquisando sobre achei este link, que achei muito interresante https://gravitational.com/blog/golang-ssh-bastion-graceful-restarts/

Comment: Acho que a dor maior é sua estratégia de deploy, tanto faz java, Go, C#, Node. Dá uma olhada nisso: https://tableless.com.br/tipos-de-deploy/

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não é possível e vc tem que reiniciar o serviço, o que é relativamente rápido.

Golang tem inúmeras outras vantagens e isso é apenas um detalhe.

Se isso for um fator crítico, uma opção seria vc portar a sua aplicação para Google Cloud Platform AppEngine, que permite que vc roteie os requests entre versões do código deployed. Isso minimiza o downtime de segundos para milissegundos, mas tem o custo de re-arquitetura e dependência da plataforma do Google.